laravel - Access origional blade file in overridden package blade file
I am creating a dynamic laravel package in which blade files can be extended. My idea is to provide a base template and extend it multiple times with same name. Let's simplify my saying
File:- package/views/index.blade.php

<h1>I am package</h1>
@stack('content')

Now Override this file as laravel documentation
File:- views/vendor/package/index.blade.php

@push('content')
    <h1>I am extended</h1>
@endpush

My desired result is
I am package
I am extended
i am creating it like addon. I have employee base. Now if i download team add on then team_id field will be added in form. Similarly if download role addon it will add  rele_id input in form.

How about if condition to include file when exists?

nice thought. But think it as plugin system and i don't have any info which field will be added

why not have a command that publishes your package views?

i am creating it like addon. I have employee base. Now if i download team add on then team_id field will be added in form. Similarly if download role addon it will add  rele_id input in form.

File:- package/views/index.blade.php

<h1>I am package</h1>
@yield('content)

File:- views/vendor/package/inde.blade.php
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <h1>I am extended</h1>
@endsection

I used to use section and yield for dynamic content. I hope this code will help you.

it says layouts not found

do you have app.blade.php in layouts folder of your laravel project?

nope, i don't have that

can you share me your project?

Provide me your contact, i will share it with you.

telegram username is dev77770. you can contact me using this.
